# python and dataframe: group by week and calculate the sum and difference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the following columns:

```
      DATE      ALFA    BETA
2016-04-26         1       3
2016-04-27         3       0
2016-04-28         0       8
2016-04-29         4       2
2016-04-30         3       1
2016-05-01        -2      -5
2016-05-02         3       0
2016-05-03         3       3
2016-05-08         1       7
2016-05-11         3       1
2016-05-12        10       1
2016-05-13         4       2
```

I would like to group the data in a weekly range but treat the alpha and beta columns differently. I would like to calculate the sum of the numbers in the `ALFA` column for each week while for the `BETA` column I would like to calculate the difference between the beginning and the end of the week. I show you an example of the expected result.

```
      DATE      sum_ALFA    diff_BETA
2016-04-26            12            3
2016-05-03             4            4
2016-05-11            17            1
```

I have tried this code but it calculates the sum for each column

```
df = df.resample('W', on='DATE').sum().reset_index().sort_values(by='DATE')
```

this is my dataset https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1fEqjINx9R5io7t_YxA9qShvNDxWRCUke

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess I'm having a different locale here (hence my week is different), you can do:

```
df.resample("W", on="DATE",closed="left", label="left"
            ).agg({"ALFA":"sum", "BETA": lambda g: g.iloc[0] - g.iloc[-1]})
            ALFA  BETA
DATE
2016-04-24    11     2
2016-05-01     4    -8
2016-05-08    18     5
```

I think there is a solution for your data with my approach. Define

```
def get_series_first_minus_last(s):
    try:
        return s.iloc[0] - s.iloc[-1]
    except IndexError:
        return 0
```

and replace the lambda call just by the function call, i.e.

```
df.resample("W", on="DATE",closed="left", label="left"
            ).agg({"ALFA":"sum", "BETA": get_series_first_minus_last})
```

Note that in the newly defined function, you could also return nan if you'd prefer that.

Comment: thank you for your help unfortunately I had this error -> IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds

Comment: Which Pandas veersion are you using?

Comment: 0.25.3 is my pandas version

Comment: I think the problem is --> lambda g: g.iloc[0] - g.iloc[-1]

Comment: This is really strange, are you using the same data as above? Or are you having empty groups somehow? I'd suspect that in the `agg` function, the lambda takes all the series constructed from column Beta for the groups. I just checked that event for series with one element, the `.iloc[-1]` accesses the only element. I'm running this on pandas 0.25.1

Comment: I just updated the question by inserting the link of my dataset. If you can help me I'll build a statue in your honor

Comment: I checked and your code is working but it crashes when I get to index number 739. Could it be a memory problem?

Comment: Sorry I won't check arbitrary files on the internet, but I think my assumption on the empty groups is right. So resample, resample all the weeks between the first and last date, also empty weeks. On these weeks you can't access using `.iloc`. So there are two possibilities: 1. avoid resample and use e.g. `groupby(df["DATE"].dt.week)` 2. create 0 data for every missing week